# How can I se author and date from Git with Label Decorations in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, svn

Been using SVN for a long time. One nice feature is that I can see who commited each file + the date they commited behind each file in the project explorer

Moving to Git and using EGit for Eclipse I no longer see this details. According to the Preferences -> Team - > Git - Label Decorations I can only use the variables

```
{staged}{dirty}{name}
```

When using SVN I have these

```
{added_flag}{dirty_flag}{name} {revision}  {date}  {author}
```

Is there any way to get more variables or a plugin that does this?